# Python Lambda giving botocore.errorfactory.InvalidLambdaResponseException when triggered on postconfirmation

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have setup AWS Lambda function that is triggered on an AWS Cognito. The trigger on a successful email confirmation. The Lambda function is in Python3.6.

I am referring to the AWS documentation for Cognito postConfirmation trigger.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html

`"response": {}`

So far I have tried returning None, {}, '{}'(empty json string) or valid dictionary like {'status':200, 'message':'the message string'} but it is giving error.

`botocore.errorfactory.InvalidLambdaResponseException: An error occurred (InvalidLambdaResponseException) when calling the ConfirmSignUp operation: Unrecognizable lambda output`

What should be a valid response for the post confirmation function?
here is the part of code.

```
from DBConnect import user

import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ua = event['request']['userAttributes']
    print("create user ua = ", ua)
    if ('name' in ua):
        name = ua['name']
    else:
        name = "guest"
    newUser = user.create(
        name = name,
        uid = ua['sub'],
        owner = ua['sub'],
        phoneNumber = ua['phone_number'],
        email = ua['email']
    )
    print(newUser)
    return '{}' #  <--- I am using literals here only.
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Yes, please share the code generating your response.

Comment: try return "", nil

Comment: The below answer worked for me. Apparently, AWS Cognito requires an entire event object that has been passed to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the event object:

`return event`

This is not obvious in the examples they provide in the documentation. You may want to check and ensure the event object does contain a response key (it should).